# What's the best way to mock a dependency in GO when the dependency doesn't expose an interface

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, mocking

Im trying to mock https://gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2 and its proven to be a nightmare. I usually use gomock but I can't because theres no interface file for the dep. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can define the interface yourself for any exported functionality of the package, remember interfaces in Go are implemented **implicitly**.

Comment: @mkopriva This is what I've been trying to do but the problem is that I have to return structs created in the package to create my interface which leads to a number of problems

Comment: What problems sepcifically? Do you mind updating your question with a description of those specific problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own interface.

It doesn't even need to be complete, either, it only needs to cover the methods you actually use.

Suppose you have a type `Foo` with the following methods: `Bar()`, `Baz()`, and `Qux()`.

And you use this in your code:

```
func Frobnicate(f *Foo) err {
    if err := f.Bar() error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Just change this to use your new custom interface:

```
type barer interface() {
    Bar() error
}
```

Then update your function signature:

```
func Frobnicate(f fooer) err {
    // The rest the same as before
```

Now create your own `fooer` implementation, and mock away.

If the type you need to mock is a simple struct with data, instead of with methods, you may wrap the method with getter/setter methods, so that an interface will work around it. Example, given this type:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}
```

You can create a wrapper:

```
type FooWrapper struct {
    Foo
}

func (w *FooWrapper) Name() string {
    return w.Foo.Name
}
```

Now the `Foo` type can be accessed using a custom interface for mocking.

Comment: This is great, would you mind elaborating on the getter/setter idea